# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo and GC_FOR_ALLOC Errors on Different Devices Android

Tags: android, android-emulator, nullpointerexception, dynamic-memory-allocation

I can see just one problem in my computer when I start and complete my Android Project. My friend see diffrent problems when he starts same project in his computer and phone. These are our logcat reports. Where is the problem, please help, thank you.

My Logcat Report :

```
05-19 19:20:22.564: D/dalvikvm(949): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1022K, 32% free 3626K/5324K, paused 233ms, total 273ms

05-19 19:20:22.564: I/dalvikvm-heap(949): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.596MB for 960016-byte allocation

05-19 19:20:22.853: D/dalvikvm(949): GC_CONCURRENT freed 7K, 15% free 4556K/5324K, paused 5ms+6ms, total 247ms

05-19 19:21:25.005: D/dalvikvm(949): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1033K, 23% free 4147K/5356K, paused 77ms+7ms, total 153ms

05-19 19:21:25.005: D/dalvikvm(949): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 44ms

05-19 19:21:25.044: I/dalvikvm-heap(949): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.143MB for 1000016-byte allocation

05-19 19:21:25.295: D/dalvikvm(949): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1499K, 43% free 3623K/6336K, paused 81ms+104ms, total 257ms

05-19 19:21:25.415: D/dalvikvm(949): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 43% free 3623K/6336K, paused 34ms, total 34ms

05-19 19:21:25.424: I/dalvikvm-heap(949): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.632MB for 1000016-byte allocation

05-19 19:21:25.534: D/dalvikvm(949): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 28% free 4600K/6336K, paused 75ms+6ms, total 108ms

05-19 19:21:25.534: D/dalvikvm(949): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 21ms

05-19 19:21:25.574: E/saveToExternalStorage()(949): open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

05-19 19:21:25.574: I/Choreographer(949): Skipped 223 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

---

Other Devices' Logcat Reports :

Emulator Logcat Report :

```
05-19 18:41:08.442: E/AndroidRuntime(798): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-19 18:41:08.442: E/AndroidRuntime(798): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.yoritgenerator/com.example.yoritgenerator.QRHandler}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 18:41:08.442: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-19 18:41:08.442: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-19 18:41:08.442: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-19 18:41:08.442: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-19 18:41:08.442: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-19 18:41:08.442: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-19 18:41:08.442: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
05-19 18:41:08.442: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 18:41:08.442: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-19 18:41:08.442: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-19 18:41:08.442: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-19 18:41:08.442: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-19 18:41:08.442: E/AndroidRuntime(798): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 18:41:08.442: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at com.example.yoritgenerator.QRHandler.onCreate(QRHandler.java:24)
05-19 18:41:08.442: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-19 18:41:08.442: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-19 18:41:08.442: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-19 18:41:08.442: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  ... 11 more
```

---

Phone Logcat Report :

```
05-19 21:47:09.701: W/dalvikvm(17334): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f672a0)
05-19 21:47:09.706: E/AndroidRuntime(17334): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-19 21:47:09.706: E/AndroidRuntime(17334): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.yoritgenerator/com.example.yoritgenerator.QRHandler}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 21:47:09.706: E/AndroidRuntime(17334):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
05-19 21:47:09.706: E/AndroidRuntime(17334):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
05-19 21:47:09.706: E/AndroidRuntime(17334):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
05-19 21:47:09.706: E/AndroidRuntime(17334):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
05-19 21:47:09.706: E/AndroidRuntime(17334):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-19 21:47:09.706: E/AndroidRuntime(17334):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-19 21:47:09.706: E/AndroidRuntime(17334):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
05-19 21:47:09.706: E/AndroidRuntime(17334):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 21:47:09.706: E/AndroidRuntime(17334):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-19 21:47:09.706: E/AndroidRuntime(17334):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
05-19 21:47:09.706: E/AndroidRuntime(17334):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
05-19 21:47:09.706: E/AndroidRuntime(17334):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-19 21:47:09.706: E/AndroidRuntime(17334): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 21:47:09.706: E/AndroidRuntime(17334):    at com.example.yoritgenerator.QRHandler.onCreate(QRHandler.java:24)
05-19 21:47:09.706: E/AndroidRuntime(17334):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
05-19 21:47:09.706: E/AndroidRuntime(17334):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
05-19 21:47:09.706: E/AndroidRuntime(17334):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
05-19 21:47:09.706: E/AndroidRuntime(17334):    ... 11 more
```

---

Our Code :

```
submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {           
            if( userPassword.getText().toString().equals(loginPassword) )
            {
                if( loginPassword.equals( defaultPassword ) )
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "DO NOT FORGET TO CHANGE DEFAULT PASSWORD!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //changePassword();

                    if(!isCreate){
                        //createMenu(); 
                        Intent qrCodeGenerate = new Intent( "com.example.yoritgenerator.QRHANDLER" );
                            startActivity( qrCodeGenerate );
                    }
```

---

QrHandler Class:

```
package com.example....

import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.WriterException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class QRHandler extends Activity
{
      @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            final EditText qrMessage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.qrText);
            final Button convertButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.generate);
            convertButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {

                     setContentView(R.layout.qr_image);
                     ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.qr_image);
                     String qrData = qrMessage.getText().toString();
                     int qrCodeDimention = 500;

                     Generator qrCodeEncoder = new Generator(qrData, null, Contents.Type.TEXT, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE.toString(), qrCodeDimention);

                      try
                      {
                          Bitmap bitmap = qrCodeEncoder.encodeAsBitmap();
                          imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                      } 
                      catch (WriterException e)
                      {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                      }

                }
            }); 







        }
}
```

Comment: the 2nd and 3rd logcat ouput clearly says its a NullPointerException indicating something is null in your code. the 1st logcat cleary indicates your doing to much work on main ui thread. move some of your work to a background thread

Comment: Yes, it throws a NullPointerException but do you have an idea why it throws?

Comment: without the code its difficult to say what happening. Post the code and the SO android community might help you